# Browse VPN Connected directory

Tags: 12.04, vpn, cisco

I've connected using Cisco VPN client from my Ubuntu to another Ubuntu machine. So now I want to browse directories of that machine which I'm connected through VPN, so how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to check "Allow other users to control your desktop" in remote ubuntu, if by browsing directories, you mean being able to click on remote machine by using your mouse.

Otherwise, You'll have to use other options like ftp to browse remote files.